# GIMP equivalent effect on GraphicsMagick (Cartoon, Enhance Despeckle)

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

Has GraphicsMagick an equivalent effect to those found in GIMP?

Filter> Enhance> Despeckle

Filter> Artistic> Cartoon

I'm using GraphicsMagick for node.js to manipulate images.

My goal is to highlight characters in the picture.

In GIMP works well with those effects. But I find no equivalent effect in GraphicsMagick.